# Change mark-paragraph behaviour

Tags: emacs

How to change default emacs mark-paragraph function behaviour to not select first empty line?

[my emacs http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1019877/e2.PNG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1019877/e2.PNG)

---

I've made Bohzidars upgraded version and it works for first line too.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-h") (lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (mark-paragraph)
                    (if (> (line-number-at-pos) 1)
                        (next-line))                    
                    (beginning-of-line)))
```

thanks guys for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the behaviour of `mark-paragraph`, but you can easily bind another command to the <kbd>C-M-h</kbd> keystroke (to resemble the original `M-h`):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-h") (lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (mark-paragraph)
                    (next-line)
                    (beginning-of-line)))
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Comment: This is a bit too naive, as it will fail, e.g., if the paragraph starts at the beginning of the file. But the basic approach is right.

Comment: You're correct, of course, but for the first paragraph one can still press `M-h` :-)

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer has two disadvantages: 1) doesn't accept arguments and 2) doesn't allow to mark more paragraphs by repeated calls (especially this is very useful). Here is my solution - it is the original mark-paragraph with a next-line command at the end. The condition assures it works also on the first of the file.

Possibly a more economic solution is to use advices, but I don't know how to use them yet :).

```
(defun rs-mark-paragraph (&optional arg allow-extend)
"The original default mark-paragraph, but doesn't mark the first
empty line. Put point at beginning of this paragraph, mark at
end.  The paragraph marked is the one that contains point or
follows point.

With argument ARG, puts mark at end of a following paragraph, so that
the number of paragraphs marked equals ARG.

If ARG is negative, point is put at end of this paragraph, mark is put
at beginning of this or a previous paragraph.

Interactively, if this command is repeated
or (in Transient Mark mode) if the mark is active,
it marks the next ARG paragraphs after the ones already marked."
  (interactive "p\np")
  (unless arg (setq arg 1))
  (when (zerop arg)
    (error "Cannot mark zero paragraphs"))
  (cond ((and allow-extend
          (or (and (eq last-command this-command) (mark t))
          (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)))
     (set-mark
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (mark))
        (forward-paragraph arg)
        (point))))
    (t
     (forward-paragraph arg)
     (push-mark nil t t)
     (backward-paragraph arg)
     (if (/= (line-number-at-pos) 1)
                        (next-line)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see a convenient way to do this. `mark-paragraph` calls `forward-paragraph` and `backward-paragraph` to do the bulk of the work, and in the documentation for `backward-paragraph`, we have "if the first real line of a paragraph is preceded by a blank line, the paragraph starts at that blank line."

The most relevant variables to look at appear to be `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate`, two regular expressions used inside paragraphs.el to figure out this sort of thing. I'd be leary of changing them though, as they are going to have quite a lot of other effects.

Another option is to write your own function that does something like the following:

```
(defun dg-mark-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (mark-paragraph)
  (goto-char (region-beginning))
  (when (= (string-match paragraph-separate (thing-at-point 'line)) 0)
    (forward-line)))
```